# Rewrite URL in Django 1.10

Tags: django, django-1.10

Looking for how to convert this to Django 1.10:

```
('^plugins/(?P<path>.*)$', 'redirect_to', {'url': '/static/plugins/%(path)s'}),
```

Basically I have ~50 files in a HTML theme that reference files at `/plugins/blah-blah` and I want to serve via `/static/plugins/blah-blah`.

So any request to `/plugins` should go to `/static/plugins` - any idea how?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can look into [**`RedirectView(django 1.10)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview):

```
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^plugins/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='static-plugin'), name='plugins'),
    ...
]
```